# Pastebin extension not installing in Scratch, shows error icon

Tags: code

When I click on the checkbox for Pastebin under Preferences->Extensions, result is the red error symbol as shown in the image:

[image: screenshot]

Log file:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 20:42:45.082713] Application.vala:155: Scratch version: 2.2.0
[_LOG_LEVEL_INFO 20:42:45.082796] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 3.16.0-43-generic
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.084547] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.saved-state'
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.085301] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.settings'
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.086481] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.services'
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 20:42:45.093573] Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-382qEDO7EE: Connection refused
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.126218] [Gtk] Connecting to session manager
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 20:42:45.130225] [Gtk] Attempting to add a widget with type GtkScrolledWindow to a GtkDialog, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkDialog can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkBox
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 20:42:45.150586] [Gtk] gtk_header_bar_pack: assertion 'gtk_widget_get_parent (widget) == NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 20:42:45.150629] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 20:42:45.265036] [Gtk] gtk_action_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_ACTION (action)' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 20:42:45.265074] Scratch will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.267315] SplitView.vala:180: WelcomeScreen shown succefully
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.269806] Settings.vala:158: Loading settings from schema 'org.pantheon.scratch.plugins.folder-manager'
[_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG 20:42:45.270178] MainWindow.vala:476: 'unsaved' directory already exists.
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 20:43:04.900835] [libpeas] pastebin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/scratch/plugins/pastebin/libpastebin.so: undefined symbol: soup_session_send_message
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 20:43:04.900918] [libpeas] Error loading plugin 'pastebin'
```

Comment: Could you start `scratch-text-editor` from terminal and use Pastebin (so meta...) to show us the output when clicking the checkbox? Anyhow, this seems to be a bug in Scratch and should be reported and dealt with [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch). I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: Added link for log

Answer (score 0):

Please report this as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch

Remember to provide the log file you posted here and any detail that might help devs reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/scratch/+bug/1483031